# I need help creating an xml file from a datagridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, export

i am trying to produce a program that will allow you to generate rows of data into a datagridview and it will allow you to export the datagridview into an xml file or import the data from the xml. I have figured out how to open an xml file and write it onto the datagridview, but i am having a hard time figuring out how to save it onto an xml.

The code i am using is from http://www.v-basic.net/2011/04/xml-import-and-export.html and it keeps showing up with an error on " my_datatable.WriteXml(save_file.FileName)"  every time i try to save database via overwriting a text file.

Here is the code:

```
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'create a openfile dialog
    Dim open_file As New OpenFileDialog

    'give its filter
    open_file.Filter = "Files (*.xml) | *.xml"
    Try
        'if ok click at opendialog
        If open_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(open_file.FileName, New XmlReaderSettings()) 'get xml data from the path

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile) 'read xml data
            'show xml data in datagridview
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'if any problem show error
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'define a save dialog
    Dim save_file As New SaveFileDialog
    save_file.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*" 'give its extension
    save_file.FilterIndex = 2 'select xml

    Dim my_datatable As New DataTable 'create a datatable
    If save_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 'if ok click

        'get datagridview source to datatable
        my_datatable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)

        'save datatable with xml format
        my_datatable.WriteXml(save_file.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If anyone has a fix to this problem it would be very much appreciated, or if there is an alternative solution to saving datagridview rows onto xml files then i will be very grateful for your code

Comment: If you look at this a bit differently it maybe easier. Consider loading/saving a Datatable to an XML file, and use the Datatable as the recordsource for the DataGridView.